# Convexity of $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TAx$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

For a function $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TAx$, where $A \in \mathbb{R^n}$ is a symmetric matrix, and its largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{max}(A) >0$ and its smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_{min}(A) <0$,

is $f(x)$ a convex function?

What I tried is:

I found the Hessian $$\nabla^2f(x) = A$$But is this positive semi-definite? How do I use the fact that its largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{max}(A) >0$ and its smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_{min}(A) <0$ from here?

Comment: It is convex if and only if $A$ is PSD, if and only if the eigenvalues of $A$ are all nonnegative, which does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: Then is $f(x)$ a concave function? I don't think so, because $-f(x)$ is not convex?

Comment: Right, your function is neither concave nor convex.

Comment: A good, small example fitting your hypotheses is $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2& 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$.  This results in $f(x,y) = x^2-y^2$.  Does that satisfy your definition of convex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a positive semidefinite matrix has all eigenvalues non-negative. However, $A$ has a negative eigenvalue $\lambda_{min}$.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, when $A$ has both positive and negative eigenvalues, the function $f(x)$ is neither convex nor concave. One way to look at it is also as a combination of concave and convex functions.

Now in case you want to extract the convex and concave part of it, you can perform decomposition of the matrix $A$ as $A = A^p + A^n$ where $A^p$ is PSD and $A^n$ is NSD. In such a case function will be
$$f(x)= f_p(x)+f_n(x) = x^TA^px+x^TA^nx$$ .

For decomposition refer:  [How to extract the positive semidefinite part of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537906/how-to-extract-the-positive-semidefinite-part-of-a-matrix)